# Javascript loading icon didn't work with JS disabled on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I Have Use a Javascript on blogger website to a loading until icon completely Loads. But That Didn't Work Without Javascript disabled on browser. Only CSS Shows How To Fix It.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
         document.getElementById('interactive');
         document.getElementById('load').style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#load{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    background:url("https://www.creditmutuel.fr/cmne/fr/banques/webservices/nswr/images/loading.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}
```

```html
<div id="load"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I found This Answer After Searching a Lot on Internet. Its the Best Use of modernizer

```js
/*! modernizr 3.5.0 (Custom Build) | MIT *
 * https://modernizr.com/download/?-setclasses !*/
!function(n,e,s){function o(n,e){return typeof n===e}function a(){var n,e,s,a,i,l,r;for(var c in f)if(f.hasOwnProperty(c)){if(n=[],e=f[c],e.name&&(n.push(e.name.toLowerCase()),e.options&&e.options.aliases&&e.options.aliases.length))for(s=0;s<e.options.aliases.length;s++)n.push(e.options.aliases[s].toLowerCase());for(a=o(e.fn,"function")?e.fn():e.fn,i=0;i<n.length;i++)l=n[i],r=l.split("."),1===r.length?Modernizr[r[0]]=a:(!Modernizr[r[0]]||Modernizr[r[0]]instanceof Boolean||(Modernizr[r[0]]=new Boolean(Modernizr[r[0]])),Modernizr[r[0]][r[1]]=a),t.push((a?"":"no-")+r.join("-"))}}function i(n){var e=r.className,s=Modernizr._config.classPrefix||"";if(c&&(e=e.baseVal),Modernizr._config.enableJSClass){var o=new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+s+"no-js(\\s|$)");e=e.replace(o,"$1"+s+"js$2")}Modernizr._config.enableClasses&&(e+=" "+s+n.join(" "+s),c?r.className.baseVal=e:r.className=e)}var t=[],f=[],l={_version:"3.5.0",_config:{classPrefix:"",enableClasses:!0,enableJSClass:!0,usePrefixes:!0},_q:[],on:function(n,e){var s=this;setTimeout(function(){e(s[n])},0)},addTest:function(n,e,s){f.push({name:n,fn:e,options:s})},addAsyncTest:function(n){f.push({name:null,fn:n})}},Modernizr=function(){};Modernizr.prototype=l,Modernizr=new Modernizr;var r=e.documentElement,c="svg"===r.nodeName.toLowerCase();a(),i(t),delete l.addTest,delete l.addAsyncTest;for(var u=0;u<Modernizr._q.length;u++)Modernizr._q[u]();n.Modernizr=Modernizr}(window,document);
```

```css
.no-js #load{display:none}
```